# copying a directory+renaming it

Tags: cp

I want to copy a directory from:

```
path1/dir1
```

to

```
path2/dir2
```

the first time I invoke

```
cp -r path1/dir1 path2/dir2
```

there's no problem, dir2 is created under path2

```
ls path2/dir2
```

bu the 2nd time, dir1 is created under path2/dir2

```
ls path2/dir2/dir1
```

Can I get the correct behavior using only `cp` ? (= without invoking `rm -f path2/dir2` )

Comment: are you trying to _replace_ `dir2` with `dir1` in `path2/`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `-T` option to cp (GNU `cp`):

```
cp -rT path2/dir2 path1/dir1
```

If you use `rsync` for this (which is probably what you want since it will avoid copying files which haven't changed), you can append a `/` to the source directory so that specifically the contents are copied rather than the directory itself. Eg:

```
rsync -r path1/dir1/ path2/dir2
```

Answer (score 2):

It's ambiguous what you want the behaviour to be when "copying" a directory to a destination that already exists.  Do you want to

- add new files only?
- add new files and update files whose contents have changed?
- add and update files, and delete files at the destination that have since been removed from the source?

Basically, what you think of as a simple copy operation is actually much more complicated — too complicated for `cp`.  In all cases, you want to use the `rsync` command instead.